# doInBackground of asyncTask not getting called?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

In my app, when I call new RetrieveFirstThreeArtUrl().execute() doInBackground isn't getting called.. does anyone know why? This code was working a few days ago, so I have no idea what's going on..

```
public class RetrieveFirstThreeArtUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    static final String APIURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15&artist=%s&album=%s";
    static final String APIURL_ARTIST = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15&artist=%s";


    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v("", "Pre");
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.v("", "Background");


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new LiveAdapter(LiveStreamFragment.this.getActivity(), oslist, LiveStreamFragment.this, list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

Comment: execute method runs AsyncTask serially so if you have called it once the next once would be started after the previous one finished

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean entirely...

Comment: Could you show you entire line of code for new RetrieveFirstThreeArtUrl().execute(). Also the access specifier for the overriden methods is protected

Comment: Do not put your `ListView` or `Adapter` code in `onPostExecute`, these should be initiated in `onCreate`.

Comment: For the case when doInBackground() is not called, is onPreExecute() called?

Comment: The call to super.onPreExecute() is a do-nothing, but is not the problem. Make sure that your call to execute() is done on the main thread.

Comment: Comment by @mohammad is referring to the fact that multiple instances of AsyncTask execute serially when started with execute().  This is described in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in section titled "Order of execution".

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

before calling `RetrieveFirstThreeArtUrl` method, write these two lines

```
static final String APIURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15&artist=%s&album=%s";
static final String APIURL_ARTIST = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=2ead17554acf667f27cf7dfd4c368f15&artist=%s";
```

And than call method `RetrieveFirstThreeArtUrl`, **one more thing**, use `protected` instead of `public`

```
public class RetrieveFirstThreeArtUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v("", "Pre");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new LiveAdapter(LiveStreamFragment.this.getActivity(), oslist, LiveStreamFragment.this, list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.v("", "Background");
        return null;
    }       
}
```